# IBM MQ connectivity issue with SSL

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

i have added all the certs to cacerts. using these cacerts and jks got from MQ team i have created a SSLConnectionFactory. and passed it to the Mqconnectionfactory. I have added VM args:

```
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
-Djavax.net.debug=all
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true
```

and we have unlimited JCE policy,  JDK 1.8 , IBM MQ all client 9.0.4.0

Sample Code

```
private SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {
            KeyStore ks;
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;

            String keystoreFile = environment.getProperty("ibmmq.keystoreFile");
            String truststoreFile = environment.getProperty("ibmmq.truststoreFile");
            String keystorePassword = environment.getProperty("ibmmq.keystorePassword");
            String trustStorePassword = environment.getProperty("ibmmq.trustStorePassword");

            try {
                ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), keystorePassword.toCharArray());
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststoreFile), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
                TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
                keyManagerFactory.init(ks, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
                sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
                logger.info("Initialized ssl socket factory... " + sslSocketFactory.toString());

            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                logger.error("KeyStoreException on getSocketFactory due to {}", e);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                logger.error("NoSuchAlgorithmException on getSocketFactory due to {}", e);
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
                logger.error("CertificateException on getSocketFactory due to {}", e);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                logger.error("FileNotFoundException on getSocketFactory due to {}", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("IOException on getSocketFactory due to {}", e);
            } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
                logger.error("UnrecoverableKeyException on getSocketFactory due to {}", e);
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                logger.error("KeyManagementException on getSocketFactory due to {}", e);
            }
            return sslSocketFactory;
        }

    private MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactoryBill() {
             MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

               try {

                   mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(environment.getProperty("ibmmq.host"));
                   mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(environment.getProperty("ibmmq.port", Integer.class));
                   mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                   mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(WMQConstants.CCSID_UTF8);
                   mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(environment.getProperty("ibmmq.channel"));
                   mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(environment.getProperty("ibmmq.queue-manager"));
                   mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(environment.getProperty("ibmmq.cipher.suite"));
                   mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLSocketFactory(getSocketFactory());
                   mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLFipsRequired(false);
                   System.out.println("mqQueueConnectionFactory initialized..!!! ==> " + mqQueueConnectionFactory.toString());
                   //System.out.println("mqQueueConnectionFactory  connection ..!!! ==> " + mqQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection());
                   //System.out.println("mqQueueConnectionFactory ..!!! ==> " + mqQueueConnectionFactory.getClientReconnectOptions());
               } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
        }

    @Bean
        public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() {
            CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
            cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapterBill());
            cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(500);
            cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheProducers(true);
            cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
            return cachingConnectionFactory;
        }

    private UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapterBill() {
             UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
             userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername(environment.getProperty("ibmmq.username"));
             userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword(environment.getProperty("ibmmq.password"));
             userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactoryBill());
             return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
       }
    @Bean
        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer sampleQueueContainer(@Autowired MessageListener listener) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
            container.setDestinationName(environment.getProperty("ibmmq.mq.name"));
            container.setMessageListener(listener);
            container.afterPropertiesSet();
            container.start();
            return container;
        }
```

Error As Follows

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9213: A communications error for 'TCP' occurred. [1=java.net.SocketException[Connection reset],4=TCP,5=sockInStream.read]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.receive(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1717) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar:9.0.4.0 - p904-L171030.1]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.receiveTSH(RemoteConnection.java:3110) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar:9.0.4.0 - p904-L171030.1]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:270) ~[spring-jms-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.sample.sampleMQConfig.sampleQueueContainer(sampleMQConfig.java:84) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.sample.sampleMQConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$701bd166.CGLIB$sampleQueueContainer$3(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.sample.sampleMQConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$701bd166$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8ac69a00.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.sample.sampleMQConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$701bd166.sampleQueueContainer(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar:9.0.4.0 - p904-L171030.1]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:357) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar:9.0.4.0 - p904-L171030.1]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:270) ~[spring-jms-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.sample.sampleMQConfig.sampleQueueContainer(sampleMQConfig.java:84) ~[classes/:?]
```

Comment: What does the queue managers `AMQERR01.LOG` show at the same time that the app gets the above error?

Comment: Surya, any update?  The error you provided from app side does not tell cause, the error on the queue manager end should provide additional information.

Comment: checking with MQ Team Josh, I'll get back to you

Comment: 07/18/2019 03:15:13 PM - Process(14047.768853) User(mqm) The channel program running under process ID 14047 for channel
'SSL_SVRCONN_CHANNEL' ended abnormally. The host name is 'xyz.com'; in some cases the host name cannot be determined and so is
shown as '????'.

Comment: Surya, that looks like only part of the error message, you can click edit below the question and add the full error, but if it is just the `AMQ9999` then that is also a generic error that says the channel ended abnormally, `AMQ9999` errors are always paired with a error before it in the log that shows the reason for the failure, so I suggest you provide that error not the `AMQ9999` error.

Comment: To put it in a fixed width font you can just proceed it and follow it by a line that contains only three backticks like ```.